# how to append to list variable with list comprehension inside for loop

Tags: python

I have two folders that contain files with same structure. Say `dir1=\home\usr1` and `dir2=\home\usr2`

I want to create two list variables(say `dir1_files`  and `dir2_files`), each one containing the file paths of each file in each directory
have managed to do so by using two for loops, one for each direcory, with the following code, but there must be a more efficient way of doing it

```
for files in os.listdir(dir1): 
        file = os.path.join(dir1, files)
        dir1_files.append(file)

for files in os.listdir(dir2): 
        file = os.path.join(dir2, files)
        dir2_files.append(file)
```

edit: after applying your suggestions i end up with the folowing which is working. Feel free to suggest even more elegant solutions

```
for dir_in in [dir1, dir2]: 
        for files in os.listdir(dir_in): 
                  file = os.path.join(dir_in, files)
                  if dir_in==dir1:  
                        dir1_files.append(file)
                  else:
                        dir2_files.append(file)
```

using python 3 in windows if its relevant

Comment: it is concise, easy to understand and works. Why does it bother you?

Comment: convert the loop into a list comprehension to get a 1liner.

Comment: thanks,I just need to understand the logic so that i can apply it to more complicated issues. I thought  list comprehension was the way. Could you maybe show me how to use list comprehension to appending to  a different variable?

Comment: or even one-linier: `dir1_files, dir2_files = [ [os.path.join(d, file) for file in  os.listdir(d)] for d in [dir1,dir2]]` but thats not nicer - its just shorter. Lines of code is **no** measurement for quality!

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the above using list comprehension as written below

```
dir_files = [os.path.join(dir, files) for files in os.listdir(dir)]
```

If there are multiple directories you need to look at you can write a for loop and iterate each directory and store the results in another list

```
dirs = []
dirlist = [dir1, dir2]
for dir in dirlist: # iterating through all directory in directory list
    dir_files = [os.path.join(dir, files) for files in os.listdir(dir)]
    dirs.append(dir_files)
```

Of course you can also apply list comprehension to the code above, but generally its better to have readable code even though there is a more efficient way of doing things.

Comment: thanks. Although I need to store files from each dir in a different variable, as each dir contains different tyoe of data that i do not want to mix together.  I edited my question in case it is clearer

Comment: Though you can use different variables, in this case it may be better to use a list instead. This way the number of directories you need to search can be arbitrary and you can index the items in the list corresponding to the given directory

Comment: If the directory names were all unique, you can also use a dictionary instead. Define each key as the unique directory name and the value as a list of corresponding files

Comment: thank you for al your input. Would you be able to show me an example of how dictionary could be used?